# how to use OleDbDataReader

Tags: database, vb.net, connection

I am totally new to vb.net, I am trying to create a database connectivity using access database. Everything goes well but whenever I create object of `OleDbDataReader` it shows an error `OleDbDataReader is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend'`

Here is my code:

```
Dim con as new OleDbConnection
con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)
Dim query as String = "my query"
Dim cmd as New OleDbCommand(query,con)
con.open()
Dim reader as new OleDbDataReader                //here comes the error
while reader.read()
      my code
end while
```

My Imports are

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.Linq.Mapping
Imports System.IO
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create a reader by yourself - a command object has to to it. So for you:

```
Dim cmd as New OleDbCommand(query,con)
con.open()
Dim reader=cmd.ExecuteReader()
while reader.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss to execute oledb  command.
Please add below syntax after defining OleDbDataReader

```
reader  = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

Comment: Oops I forgot to mention in my code. But actually I've written that line in my code.